# Why does my webpage hang when using "redirect_to" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide, redirecttoaction

I am developing my first Rails app in the Cloud9 IDE.  Whenever I try and use `redirect_to`, the webpage just hangs.  What am I doing wrong?

I have a UsersController class:

> ```
> def index
>     @users = User.all
> end
> def new
>     @user = User.new
> end
> def create
>     @user = User.new(user_params)
>     @user.save
>     redirect_to users_path        
> end
> private 
> def user_params
>     params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
> end
> ```

On the index.html.erb view I have created a small form for adding users and then a list showing all users.

I want to create a new user and then redirect back to the index view to show the new user added to the list.

Here is the index.html.erb form code

```
 <%= form_for :user, url: {action: 'create'} do |u| %>

  <%= u.label :name %>
  <%= u.text_field :name %>

  <%= u.label :email %>
  <%= u.text_field :email %>

  <%= u.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

When I hit submit on the create form, the webpage hangs.  If I reload it, then it has worked - it shows the new user has been created and added to the list.

I'm a new to Rails so don't know if my syntax is right, but I've tried a whole different bunch of ways of using `redirect_to` - none of them work.  Help!

For the record, my routes are:

> ```
> users_index GET    /users/index(.:format)     users#index
>       users GET    /users(.:format)           users#index
>            POST   /users(.:format)           users#create
>   new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)       users#new
>  edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)  users#edit
>      user GET    /users/:id(.:format)       users#show
>           PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)       users#update
>           PUT    /users/:id(.:format)       users#update
>           DELETE /users/:id(.:format)       users#destroy
>      root GET    /                          users#index
> ```